How to rerun skipped test cases using TestNG?
I tried to re-run testng skipped test cases in the following way and I am getting 'Test ignored.' message. How to fix this issue using TestNG?
I tried the solution mentioned in How to rerun skipped tests in testNG? & still didn't work.
public class TestClass{
    private static int counter = 5;

    @Test(alwaysRun = true)
    public void skipTest() throws IOException {
        throw new SkipException("Skipping this test case intentionally");
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterSuite(ITestContext ctx) {
        IResultMap skippedTests = ctx.getSkippedTests();

        while (skippedTests.size() > 0 && (counter--) > 0) {
            List<XmlInclude> includeMethods
                    = skippedTests.getAllMethods()
                    .stream()
                    .map(m -> new XmlInclude(m.getMethodName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(this.getClass().getName());
            xmlClass.setIncludedMethods(includeMethods);

            XmlTest test = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest();
            List<XmlClass> classes = test.getXmlClasses();
            classes.remove(0);
            classes.add(xmlClass);

            TestRunner newRunner = new TestRunner(new Configuration(),
                    ctx.getSuite(),
                    test,
                    false,
                    null,
                    new ArrayList<>());
            newRunner.run();

            Set<String> newPassed = newRunner.getPassedTests().getAllResults()
                    .stream()
                    .map(ITestResult::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            IResultMap passedTests = ctx.getPassedTests();
            Iterator<ITestResult> iter = skippedTests.getAllResults().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                ITestResult result = iter.next();
                if (newPassed.contains(result.getName())) {
                    result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
                    passedTests.addResult(result, result.getMethod());

                    //remove the test from list of skipped tests.
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. This includes HTML.
